# ExpressJS in a TypeScript class

Tags: express, typescript

All ExpressJS and TypeScript examples I could find use

```
import * as express from "express";

let app = express();
app.use("/", express.static("/"));
```

However, I want to use the class approach:

```
import * as express from "express";

export class ServerApp {

    private app: express.Express = express();

    public configure {
        this.app.use('/', express.static("/");
    }
}
```

Trying to access the `use` method on the private variable gives an argument type warning.

I want to use strong typing so `private app: any` will not work. How can I solve this problem, or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the latest express typings, the type for app is called Application, not Express. The following file `test.ts` compiles just fine

```
import * as express from "express";

export class ServerApp {

    private app: express.Application = express();

    public configure() {
        this.app.use('/', express.static("/"));
    }
}
```

if you put it in an empty directory and do

```
npm install typescript
npm install typings
./node_modules/.bin/typings install -G dt~node
./node_modules/.bin/typings install express
./node_modules/.bin/tsc test.ts typings/index.d.ts
```

it will work.

However, there is more than one way to install typings for express. If you don't need compatiblity with  typescript < 2.0 (2.0 was released a few days ago), you can just

```
npm install typescript
npm install @types/express
./node_modules/.bin/tsc test.ts
```

and again it will work. If you look at installed `types-metadata.json` for  `express-serve-static-core`, you notice that it uses types-2.0 branch of DefinitelyTyped:

```
"sourceRepoURL": "https://www.github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped",
"sourceBranch": "types-2.0",
```

The third way to install is

```
../node_modules/.bin/typings install -G dt~express
```

this will take it from the main branch of DefinitelyTyped, which, as @Aphelion discovered, contains [problematic commit](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/1e92c152ee1b7af9b39f01789de37e2e463fd0de) that removes a number of `use` overloads, causing the error in question.

Comment: It indeed compiles correctly. For some reason however, my tool `WebStorm` gives this warning but gets its definitions from `express-serve-static-core`. Any Idea why it would prefer this over the normal definitions?

Comment: This might cause the problem:https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/1e92c152ee1b7af9b39f01789de37e2e463fd0de

Comment: Yes you are right! Whatever I did probably used types-2.0 branch of DefinitelyTyped which does not contain that commit. I updated the answer. BTW I also use WebStorm, and it seems to me that it just uses whatever is installed in node_modules and typings.

Comment: Unfortunately the commit has been merged to the typings2.0 branche.

Comment: I just checked again with `npm install @types/express` and it still works. Either it's not published on npm yet, or that commit is not really the problem.